# ATOM to RSS feeds converter

Tags: php, rss, feed, atom-feed

I found this working converter: http://feedmix.novaclic.com/atom2rss.php

However I would like to have a source code. Where can I found a working one for PHP?

Comment: Try searching [github](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20atom%20to%20rss%20php%20site:github.com) and [sourceforge](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20atom%20to%20rss%20php%20site:sourceforge.net). Both of those are good source code repositories.

Comment: what do you need ? I have a class that process rss/atom into php data - you want that ?

Comment: Many parser libraries will accept RSS or Atom. Can you parse both? Why do you need to produce RSS as output?

Comment: My RSS reader does not work with some Atom feeds.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the owner of that website and asked for it?

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find a working one for PHP?

**Source files:** https://github.com/pornel/atom2rss 
  Examples: http://atom.geekhood.net/ 
  Live demo: http://devtacular.com/utilities/atomtorss/